# echo textarea in php

Tags: php

Please let me know How to echo textarea, Tried several versions but dint work. The whole page is in php. I am using codeigniter framework

```
echo "<textarea name='openletter'  id='openletter' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>"; <?php echo "$data['openletter']"; ?>  </textarea>";
```

Comment: you cannot echo only textarea and you can echo others?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing very basic PHP functionality and knowledge, so I'd advice you to read some coursework on beginner PHP. also, this should fix your problem

```
<textarea name='openletter'  id='openletter' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'><?php echo $data['openletter'];?></textarea>
```

if you want everything inside an Echo :

```
echo "<textarea name='openletter'  id='openletter' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>". $data['openletter'] ."</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
echo "<textarea name='openletter'  id='openletter' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>";

echo $data['openletter'];

echo "</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to do it with alternative language construct:

```
echo "<textarea name='openletter'  id='openletter' style='width: 565px;' rows='8' cols='60'>{$data['openletter']}</textarea>";
```

Note the use of `{` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

According to codeigniter ,best way to this is by using

> form_textarea()

using **from helper**

```
<?php
$data = array(           
             'name'        => 'field_name',
             'id'          => 'field_id',
             'value'       => 'field_value'

            );

$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_textarea($data);

?>
```